# Reading in ASCII file with uncommon formatting in Python

Tags: python, csv, import, ascii, genfromtxt

I've never worked with importing data from an ASCII file and I've noticed that different ASCII files have different formats so trying to find a general solution that works for any format has proven challenging for me.

I have a `.dat` (ASCII) file that I need to read in and extract the variables (*see snippet of txt at bottom of question*). Below is code from different attempts (separated by ###) of me trying to figure out how to read in the data.

```
f_41 = open(fileRS41, 'r')
data_41 = f_41.read()
for line in data_41:
    print(repr(line))
data_41.close()

############################

f = open(fileRS41, 'r')

# Read and ignore header lines
header1 = f.readline()
header2 = f.readline()
header3 = f.readline()

# Loop over lines and extract variables of interest
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    name = columns[1] # Not sure what the different numbers do but this was code from another solution
    j = float(columns[1]) # ERROR: string can't be converted to float
    print(name, j)
f.close()

############################
from astropy.io import ascii
data = ascii.read(f_41, guess=False)  
print(data) 
############################
x = np.genfromtxt(f_41, dtype=None)
```

Another option would be to convert this into a CSV file first and then use Pandas to work with it. However, when I do convert, the variable names get imported as a column stacked on top of each other versus one variable name per its respective column.

```
# convert ASCII to CSV
f = open(file, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

with open("FILEOUT.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for l in lines:
        asdf = l.split()
        writer.writerow(asdf)
print("out?")
```

.dat file relevant sample:

```
Generated by Rfunction:  Get.mw41.edt.func2 
============> Radisonde_info:
RS_type:        RS41-SGP
RS_config:      -32768
RS_serialnum:   R3340183
RS_freq:        403
RS__windtype:   ccGPS
=============> Station_info:
Station:        HUBV_RS41SGP
Latitude:       39.0563
Longitude:      -76.8755
Altitude:       52.3
SW version:     MW41 2.15.0
Start time:     2020-01-23 06:46:41
=============> Variables & units - Vaisala EDT
NA_numeric value:  -9999
NA_string:  xx or NA
-----------------------------
      Variable       Unit
          time        sec
            xx         NA
            Ta          K
            RH          %
       v(S->N)        m/s
       u(E->W)        m/s
        Height          m
         press        hPa
            Td          K
            MR       g/Kg
            DD        dgr
            FF        m/s
    Ascend_FLG  (0-N,1-Y)
            xx         NA
            xx         NA
           Lon        dgr
           Lat        dgr
            xx         NA
            xx         NA
            xx         NA
=============> Data:
   0.00  -9999.    268.37    85.00      0.00      0.00         52.3   1023.19    266.24     2.22       0.00      0.00 1  -9999.  -9999.   -76.8755    39.0563  -9999.  -9999.  -9999.
   0.81  -9999.    268.46    83.38      0.46      0.86         54.5   1022.90    266.08     2.19     241.86      0.98 1  -9999.  -9999.   -76.8757    39.0564  -9999.  -9999.  -9999.
```

Comment: Images of text are not very useful as we can't parse them! Pictures of code and data are discouraged.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the file link.

Comment: I don’t want to click a link - please edit a relevant sample the text of your dat file into your question.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a relevant sample of the txt file and removed the link. Thanks for sharing tips on how to better ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution that works but I would like to avoid hard-coding column headers and be able to read them directly from the ASCII file:

```
# set the directory for data files
fileRS41 = 'filename.dat'

# load text from .dat files
f41 = np.loadtxt(fileRS41, skiprows = 40)

# create column names for variables
c = ['time' , 'xx0', 'temp', 'RH', 'v(S_N)', 'u(E_W)', 'height', 'pressure', 'Td', 'mixingratio', 'DD', 'FF', 'Ascend_FLG', 'xx1', 'xx2', 'lon', 'lat', 'xx3', 'xx4', 'xx5']

# skip columns when reading in file and converting to dataFrame
skip = ['xx0', 'DD', 'FF', 'Ascend_FLG', 'xx1', 'xx2', 'xx3', 'xx4', 'xx5']

# convert to Pandas Dataframe
df_f41 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(f41, exclude=skip, columns = c)
```